# What's the error with my scripts regarding SQL Pivot function?

Tags: sql

Can you please advise why system alert syntax error?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        svc_no,
        month_yyyymm,
        prd_desc,
        mrc
    FROM (
        SELECT
            s.svc_no,
            m.month_yyyymm,
            Sum(r.mth_net_rentl_amt) mrc,
            CASE
                WHEN Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '%MOBILE%BROADBAND%' THEN 'BBOM'
                WHEN Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '% ENTERPRISE SOLUTION%' THEN 'BES'
                WHEN Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '% INT%' THEN 'BIS'
                ELSE 'MainPlanMRC'
            END prd_desc
        FROM tbl1 s
        JOIN tbl2 m ON m.subs_skey = s.subs_skey
        JOIN tbl3 r ON m.trkg_id = r.emf_trkg_id
        JOIN tbl4 p ON p.prd_skey = m.prd_skey
        JOIN tbl5 t ON t.lookup_cd = s.cust_clasfn_cd
        WHERE m.month_yyyymm = 202106
        AND s.end_dt = 99991231
        AND s.op_svc_type_id = 'MT'
        AND s.arbor_svc_type_id = '501'
        AND t.table_abbrev = 'CUST_CLASSIFICATION'
        AND (
            Lower(t.desc_text) NOT LIKE '%bizsales%'
            OR Lower(t.desc_text) NOT LIKE '%bizseg%'
        )
        AND (
            (
                Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '%MOBILE%BROADBAND%'
                OR Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '%ENTERPRISE SOLUTION%'
                OR Upper(p.prd_desc) LIKE '%INT%'
            )
            OR p.main_prd_ind = 1
        )
        GROUP BY
            s.svc_no,
            m.month_yyyymm,
            p.prd_desc
        ) AS a 
        PIVOT (Sum(mrc) FOR prd_desc IN (
            'BBOM' AS bbom_mrc,
            'BES' AS bes_mrc,
            'BIS' AS bis_mrc,
            'BEP' AS bep_mrc,
            'BBUL' AS bbul_mrc,
            'DRS' AS drs_mrc,
            'EEDR' AS eedr_mrc,
            'MOBILESHARE' AS mobileshare_mrc,
            'DATAMORE' AS datamore_mrc,
            'TALKMORE' AS talkmore_mrc,
            'MULTISIM' AS multisim_mrc,
            'DATAX2' AS datax2_mrc,
            'DATAX3' AS datax3_mrc,
            'MOBILE_THREAT' AS mobile_threat_mrc,
            'ZONEALARM' AS zonealarm_mrc,
            'MainPlanMRC' AS mainplan_mrc
         )
    ) AS pvt
)
```

Comment: https://www.markheath.net/post/effective-debugging-with-divide-and-conquer

Comment: what is the RDBMS ?

Comment: What's the exact error message ?

Comment: Certainly in SQL Server, the `IN` clause can only contain column identifiers, not literal strings and aliases.

Comment: Error message is 'Syntax error: Exception parsing query near 'PIVOT'

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this is Pivot function, IN clause is different from normal I think.

Comment: @stevensun - I meant the `IN` for `PIVOT`. The syntax is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) for SQL Server. It's *more* restrictive than the `IN` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Generally pivot (MS Sql Server syntax) looks like

```
 SELECT svc_no,
   month_yyyymm,
   [BBOM] as mrc_bbom,
   [BES] as mrc_bes,
   [BIS] as mrc_bis,
   [BEP] as mrc_bep ..

 FROM (
      ..
      ) as a 
 PIVOT (Sum(mrc) FOR prd_desc IN ( [BBOM] ,
                                   [BES] ,
                                   [BIS] ,
                                   [BEP]  ..
                                  )
       ) as pvt
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e568e9cbe242fe2e134673c044afb885)

Comment: Thank you!
I've already had a case when clause to define prd_desc, and prd_desc has already selected in the main query, seems like your version ignored this.
Please confirm. thanks.

Comment: I just skipped the inner query aliased `a` text for brevity. Seems like this query requires no changes, including `prd_desc` expression.

Comment: This is a valid MS Sql Server pivot syntax, added the fiddle.

Comment: I've just managed to get the scripts executed. Thank you!!